# MySQL restarted abruptly

Tags: mysql

Please see the log below and make out the reason behind abrupt MySQL restart?

> 110324 17:19:37 - mysqld got signal
>   11; This could be because you hit a
>   bug. It is also possible that this
>   binary or one of the libraries it was
>   linked against is corrupt, improperly
>   built, or misconfigured. This error
>   can also be caused by malfunctioning
>   hardware. We will try our best to
>   scrape up some info that will
>   hopefully help diagnose the problem,
>   but since we have already crashed,
>   something is definitely wrong and this
>   may fail.
>
> key_buffer_size=2097152
>   read_buffer_size=2093056
>   max_used_connections=155
>   max_connections=800
>   threads_connected=105 It is possible
>   that mysqld could use up to 
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size +
>   sort_buffer_size)*max_connections =
>   3275641 K bytes of memory Hope that's
>   ok; if not, decrease some variables in
>   the equation.
>
> thd=0x21525240 Attempting backtrace.
>   You can use the following information
>   to find out where mysqld died. If you
>   see no messages after this, something
>   went terribly wrong... Cannot
>   determine thread, fp=0x46946088,
>   backtrace may not be correct. Stack
>   range sanity check OK, backtrace
>   follows: (nil) New value of
>   fp=0x21525240 failed sanity check,
>   terminating stack trace! Please read
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/using-stack-trace.html
>   and follow instructions on how to
>   resolve the stack trace. Resolved
>   stack trace is much more helpful in
>   diagnosing the problem, so please do 
>   resolve it Trying to get some
>   variables. Some pointers may be
>   invalid and cause the dump to abort...
>   thd->query at 0x2aab98514ee0  is
>   invalid pointer thd->thread_id=3133802
>   The manual page at
>   http://www.mysql.com/doc/en/Crashing.html
>   contains information that should help
>   you find out what is causing the
>   crash.
>
> Number of processes running now: 0
>   110324 17:19:37  mysqld restarted
>   110324 17:19:37 [Warning] The syntax
>   for replication startup options is
>   deprecated and will be removed in
>   MySQL 5.2. Please use 'CHANGE MASTER'
>   instead. 110324 17:19:38  InnoDB:
>   Database was not shut down normally!
>   InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>   InnoDB: Reading tablespace information
>   from the .ibd files... InnoDB:
>   Restoring possible half-written data
>   pages from the doublewrite InnoDB:
>   buffer... 110324 17:19:42  InnoDB:
>   Starting log scan based on checkpoint
>   at InnoDB: log sequence number 75
>   131221842. InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 75
>   132702399 110324 17:19:43  InnoDB:
>   Starting an apply batch of log records
>   to the database... InnoDB: Progress in
>   percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
>   13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
>   26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
>   39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
>   52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
>   65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
>   78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
>   91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99  InnoDB:
>   Apply batch completed InnoDB: In a
>   MySQL replication slave the last
>   master binlog file InnoDB: position 0
>   232, file name lalithamba-bin.003081
>   InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file
>   position 0 31496822, file name
>   /data/db/MySql_5.0.41/log/mysql_repl_log/amritamba-bin.009607
>   110324 17:19:49  InnoDB: Started; log
>   sequence number 75 132702399 110324
>   17:19:49 [Note] Recovering after a
>   crash using
>   /data/db/MySql_5.0.41/log/mysql_repl_log/amritamba-bin
>   110324 17:19:50 [Note] Starting crash
>   recovery... 110324 17:19:50 [Note]
>   Crash recovery finished. 110324
>   17:19:51 [Note]
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for
>   connections. Version: '5.0.41-log' 
>   socket:
>   '/data/db/MySql_5.0.41/mysql.sock' 
>   port: 3306  MySQL Community Server
>   (GPL) 110324 17:56:48 [Note]
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Normal
>   shutdown
>
> 110324 17:56:50  InnoDB: Starting
>   shutdown... 110324 17:56:53  InnoDB:
>   Shutdown completed; log sequence
>   number 75 132702778 110324 17:56:53
>   [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld:
>   Shutdown complete
>
> 110324 17:56:53  mysqld ended
>
> 110324 17:56:56  mysqld started 110324
>   17:56:56 [Warning] The syntax for
>   replication startup options is
>   deprecated and will be removed in
>   MySQL 5.2. Please use 'CHANGE MASTER'
>   instead. 110324 17:56:58  InnoDB:
>   Started; log sequence number 75
>   132702778 110324 17:56:58 [Note]
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for
>   connections. Version: '5.0.41-log' 
>   socket:
>   '/data/db/MySql_5.0.41/mysql.sock' 
>   port: 3306  MySQL Community Server
>   (GPL) 110324 17:57:20 [Note] Slave SQL
>   thread initialized, starting
>   replication in log
>   'lalithamba-bin.003081' at position
>   31228372, relay log
>   '/data/db/MySql_5.0.41/log/mysql_repl_log/amritamba_mysql_relaylog.005857'
>   position: 31228514 110324 17:57:20
>   [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to
>   master
>   'ReplSlave@192.168.111.116:3306', 
>   replication started in log
>   'lalithamba-bin.003081' at position
>   31228372

Comment: You're not paying me and I'm not working for you. No reason for me to make anything out of this wall of text.

Comment: Maybe you could enlighten us with some troubleshooting steps you've already tried and at least *appear* to be putting some effort in yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Your memory statistics read close to insane:

```
key_buffer_size=2097152
read_buffer_size=2093056
max_used_connections=155
max_connections=800
threads_connected=105 

It is possible that mysqld could use up to  key_buffer_size + 
(read_buffer_size +  sort_buffer_size)*max_connections = 
3 275 641 K bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
```

That means that at the time of the crash it is not completely unlikely that your mysqld has been killed by the OOM killer or a similar mechanism in your operating system. If that was the case, additional information will be in the kernel message log (not the MySQL log) with the same or a similar timestamp as the crash message (110324 17:19:37 = 24-Mar-2011, 17:19:37 local time).

Also, you should seriously get a review of your MySQL configuration. Not just the memory stuff, your replication configuration also produces startup warnings, and the version you are using (5.0.41) is seriously outdated (current version is two major releases further - 5.5). The version of MySQL you are using was released 01 May 2007, almost 4 years ago.

This has no place in any production configuration whatsoever.